# Sending email from iCloud with a different Reply-to field

Tags: icloud, email, smtp

I want to use iCloud's email service (**me.com**) as the ultimate destination for my incoming mail, *as well as the repository of all my Sent mail*.  And when people reply to my email, I want it to be sent to **myname@pobox.com**.  (In other words, I want my **pobox.com** address to be my "official" address -- the only one anyone sees in their contact lists or their emailer's auto-complete suggestion list: anything else merely promotes confusion!)

In order for my outgoing mail to be copied to my iCloud **SENT** folder, I need to send it via iCloud's SMTP server.  But there does not appear to be a way to configure OSX Mail (or iOS Mail) to send mail via **smtp.mail.me.com** but include a Reply-to of **myname@pobox.com**.

- Is there a way to send mail out through iCloud while specifying my
  own preferred **Reply-to** address?
- Or, barring that, is there a workaround that will allow me to specify
  my preferred **Reply-to** address while keeping my SENT mail in
  iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works for iCloud account but it works for regular email accounts, try the following.

Go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars and then choose the iCloud mail account. If there is account information showing the `Address` as xxxx@me.com simply edit the field to be something like `xxxx@me.com,myname@pobox.com`

When you send an email tap on the `Cc/Bcc,From:` field, then click on the `From:` field. You should be presented with a listing of email address to choose.

Comment: The address field for my iCloud mail account is myname@pobox.com !!  **And it's un-editable.**  (FWIW, "myname@pobox.com" is also my Apple i.d., which is why it didn't leap out at me at first.)

Comment: It may be that this trick doesn't work with iCloud accounts. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

afragen's method will work. You cannot modify the addresses if you set up the mail account as default "iCloud". Turn off mail in your iCloud settings then make a new mail account. Do not choose any of the default options for the listed services. Make a custom mail setup and you will be able enter everything manually as afragen has written.

You will have to enter the iCloud server for incoming, your own smtp for outgoing and your email address as mentioned.

You can enter more than one email address with comma between each. The first email addres you list will be the default send from for that account. You will have a drop down to select the others if you need that option.

Answer (score -1):

On the compose window on Mail, you can customize it using the square button at the left side below/side subject field. There you can add the field answer to: 
Using this should work.