# How can I send an email from within iCloud.com using a different email address?

Tags: icloud, email, dns, hosts, smtp

I have my own private domain hosting solution with email, for example, test@test.com.

When I am using the iCloud.com website from my browser, let's say for creating a spreadsheet, I will want to shed that with other people, however, I don't want to send it from my iCloud email address, instead I want to be able to send emails from within iCloud.com using my other email address, e.g., test@test.com, how can I do this?

Please note I am NOT asking to be able to send from iCloud from Mail, this is different.
I believe my question is not the same as "Can I use a non "me.com" address to send email with iCloud".

If I am logged onto iCloud.com through my browser, I want to be able to use the mail part to send emails from my test@test.com address and not my name@icloud.com address.

I have checked the settings within iCloud and was not able to find anything.

Comment: However, you might be able to trick things with a reply address... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/sending-email-from-icloud-with-a-different-reply-to-field?rq=1